# How to use Ajax to not reload content every time?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I'm fairly new to the coding world and currently working as a beginner webdev specialist; my boss asked me to enhance the web-site in such a way that only the inner content is reloaded when you reload the page and the top panel/side bars/navbars stay the same.
I heard that there is a way to do that with Ajax/jQuery but I'm not that experienced with JS.

Can someone post some general code that I can use in such situations? Do I wrap the initial code in it somehow?

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: So read a tutorial on Ajax

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention that what technology you are using. In angular, no need of specific ajax code it has its own logic to do the things. In PHP or other you can use ajax. Two things are considerable,

**#** If you reload the page or refresh the browser then the whole web page will be reloaded. 
**#** Ajax can only help you to fetch content without refresh the entire page into a specific area wherever you want. but if you reload the browser then whole page reloads.

I suggest you to first read about the js/jquery and ajax. And how to use it in your project with which technology you used.